# How can I get correct next execution time as datetime form celery is_due method?

Tags: python, datetime, celery, timedelta

celery.schedules.crontab is_due method returns next execution time as seconds.
But when we got seconds time and calculate that with datetime, result is broken.
Here's code:

```
from celery.schedules import crontab
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
c = crontab(0, 0, day_of_month=2)
now = datetime.utcnow().replace(year=2015,month=7,day=31)
r = c.is_due(now)
execution_time = now + timedelta(seconds=r.next)
print(execution_time)
>>> 2015-08-29 23:59:59.999605
```

I expect this code should returns 2015-08-02....
Why time is different? Maybe my calculation process is broken.
Could you tell me proper calculation process?

Comment: Try - `execution_time = now + timedelta(seconds=r[1])` .

Comment: I tried but still got not correct time.
`2015-08-29 23:59:59.986097`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand the internal of crontab well, but the correct parameter passed to is_due [The first time of calling is_due()] is the current time, like `c.is_due(datetime.now())`. Otherwise, the is_due will return `schedstate(is_due=True, next=...)`

Comment: You're right. I need to mock datetime.now() through entire context.